# Creating personalized XML from SQL query Data result

Tags: xml, sql-server-2012

I am trying to create an xml result through my SQL data result with a specific format. But I have no idea how will I be able to generate. I know a basic way to call

Currently as per below Sql Query

```
DECLARE @cityFrom VARCHAR(10)= 'Berlin';
DECLARE @CustomerFrom VARCHAR(25)= CASE
     WHEN @cityFrom = 'Berlin'
     THEN 'ID_1'
     WHEN @cityFrom = 'London'
     THEN 'ID_2'
     WHEN @cityFrom = 'Tsawassen'
     THEN 'ID_3'
     WHEN @cityFrom = 'Mannheim'
     THEN 'ID_4'
 END;

    SELECT CustomerID,
       CustomerName,
       Country
    FROM Customers
    WHERE City = @cityFrom;
FOR XML PATH (''), ROOT('table')
```

I am getting this output

```
<table>
  <CustomerID>1</CustomerID>
  <CustomerName>Alfreds Futterkiste</CustomerName>
  <Country>Germany</Country>
</table>
```

But I would like to get my expected result as below,

```
<ID_1>
    <Parameter key="ID_1_CustomerID">1</Parameter>
    <Parameter key="ID_1_CustomerName">Alfreds Futterkiste</Parameter>
    <Parameter key="ID_1_Country">Germany</Parameter>
</ID_1>
```

I am calling @CustomerFrom as I wanted to post it as `<ID_1>...</ID_1>`. Also I know `<table>...</table>` is posted via ROOT('table') but I am not able to pass ROOT(@CustomerFrom) for ...

Question: Is there any solution how can I get my expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bad idea to name an element with a variable (more about this later). But this *can* be solved:

```
DECLARE @mockup TABLE(CustomerID INT, CustomerName VARCHAR(100),Country VARCHAR(100),City VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @mockup VALUES(99,'TestName','Germany','Berlin');

DECLARE @cityFrom VARCHAR(10)= 'Berlin';

DECLARE @CustomerFrom VARCHAR(25)= CASE
     WHEN @cityFrom = 'Berlin'
     THEN 'ID_1'
     WHEN @cityFrom = 'London'
     THEN 'ID_2'
     WHEN @cityFrom = 'Tsawassen'
     THEN 'ID_3'
     WHEN @cityFrom = 'Mannheim'
     THEN 'ID_4'
 END;

SELECT @CustomerFrom + '_CustomerID' AS [Parameter/@key]
       ,CustomerID AS [Parameter]
       ,''
       ,@CustomerFrom + '_CustomerName' AS [Parameter/@key]
       ,CustomerName AS [Parameter]
       ,''
       ,@CustomerFrom + '_Country' AS [Parameter/@key]
       ,Country AS [Parameter]
FROM @mockup
FOR XML PATH('ReplaceThis');
```

In the next step you'd have to cast this to `NVARCHAR(MAX)` and use `REPLACE` to get your `ID_1` into the root node...

I don't know, if the *expected result* needs to be this way...

It is a very bad idea to push information (*content*) into an element's name. Instead of `<ID_1>` I'd suggest something like `<ID location="1">`.

And instead of `ID_1_CustomerID` I'd use two attributes or take this information from the level above.

Try this:

```
SELECT @CustomerFrom AS [@location]
       ,'CustomerID' AS [Parameter/@key]
       ,CustomerID AS [Parameter]
       ,''
       ,'CustomerName' AS [Parameter/@key]
       ,CustomerName AS [Parameter]
       ,''
       ,'Country' AS [Parameter/@key]
       ,Country AS [Parameter]
FROM @mockup
FOR XML PATH('ID');
```

the result

```
<ID location="ID_1">
  <Parameter key="CustomerID">99</Parameter>
  <Parameter key="CustomerName">TestName</Parameter>
  <Parameter key="Country">Germany</Parameter>
</ID>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the output which I have shown in my description is a required output format I can't change that.

Comment: But is it possible to push information (content) into an element's name `<ID_1>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this using Xml Linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml = "<table>\n" +
                            "<CustomerID>1</CustomerID>\n" +
                            "<CustomerName>Alfreds Futterkiste</CustomerName>\n" +
                            "<Country>Germany</Country>\n" +
                            "</table>";

            XElement table = XElement.Parse(xml);
            int id = (int)table.Element("CustomerID");

            XElement xID = new XElement("ID_1");

            foreach (XElement element in table.Elements())
            {
                xID.Add(new XElement("Parameter",  new object[]  {new XAttribute("key", "ID_" + id.ToString() + "_" + element.Name.LocalName), (string)element}));
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have already received my answer which is given by @Shnugo And you are not getting it I am returning not only values but also field name of every value in a specific format which is `<Parameter key ="....`

Comment: And about inserting into XML I have a post that question in that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52768286/saving-childnode-to-xml-from-a-string-variable). Same for that as well I am not only inserting values to an XML file but also full node in a format.